# Open Website and execute its Javascript

Tags: javascript, bash, google-chrome, firefox

I want to send a Request to a Webpage multiple times and also executes the included JavaScipt, like a normal browser.
How i can automate this task?

It dose not matter if the request send from a linux server (phantomJS is not installed, and can't be) or a Chrome/Firefox Browser.

Comment: you could make a chrome extension

Comment: Ok. i have to check, how to build an extension

Comment: I don't know for what you need that, but it's quite easy, you can start from here, if you understand the logic of the `manifest` file then is simply javascript. You can start from [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)